# bash ps1 only executes a script once on new terminal windows

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, ps1

I have a very simple ps1 script in my .bashrc file, this excutes a random script generator called blah.

```
export PS1="\[$(tput bold)\]\[$(tput setaf 1)\]\\$  \[$(tput sgr0)\] $PWD :: **$(. blah)** ::"
```

the blah script simply should export a random string each time in the shell....

```
function silly {
     local RANDOMQUOTE=$[ ($RANDOM % 10 ) ] local fooey=('rand1' 'rand2' 'rand3' 'rand4' 'rand5'); 
     echo ${fooey[RANDOMQUOTE]}
}

silly
```

However it seems this script is only excuted each time I create a new window in iterm, and of course this means the script is no longer random!

Example of the random function not being called each time:

```
$   /Users/username :: rand2 ::
$   /Users/username :: rand2 ::
$   /Users/username :: rand2 ::
$   /Users/username :: rand2 ::
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Just starting to learn bash so apologies for lack of terminology, edit at will!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in [Single/double quotes ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16902905/1983854):

> The "$PWD" resolves immediately. (...) When you set to '$PWD', it does
>   not resolve immediately, so it resolves when used, and changes when
>   you change directories.

So change

```
export PS1="[$(tput bold)][$(tput setaf 1)]\$ [$(tput sgr0)] $PWD :: $(. blah) ::"
```

for

```
export PS1='[$(tput bold)][$(tput setaf 1)]\$ [$(tput sgr0)] $PWD :: $(. blah) ::'
```

That is, `PS1='<code>'` instead of `PS1="<code>"`.